# Define Model Factory with nested resource in Laravel

Tags: laravel, internationalization, factory, nested-resources

I have Articles with translations and I am trying to created a seeder for it.

I have a model factory to define a simple Article as follows:

```
$factory->define(\App\Article::class, function () {
    return [];
});
```

And ArticleTranslation

```
$factory->defineAs(\App\ArticleTranslation::class, 'en_US', function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\en_US\Person($faker));

    return [
        'locale' => 'en',
        'title' => $faker->realText(40),
        'content' => $faker->realText(200),
    ];
});
```

I can use the article factory and for each one add a translation like this:

```
    factory(\App\Article::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($article) {
        $article->translations()->save(factory(\App\ArticleTranslation::class, 'en_US')->make());
    });
```

However I believe there must be a way to define the Article factory in a way that requests the translations itself.

How can I do this?